# Create table with multiple rows with popupcontrolextender in gridview

Tags: sql, vb.net

I have the following function that returns only the 1st row of data and puts it in a nice table. My knowledge in this area is limited in that I don't know how to create the table to return multiple rows. Can you show me how to change this to return all rows, no matter how many there are? my sql select statement may return 0 rows or many rows.

thanks:

```
<System.Web.Services.WebMethodAttribute(), System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptMethodAttribute()> _
    Public Shared Function GetDynamicContent(contextKey As String) As String
        Dim constr As String = "Data Source=my data source"
        Dim query As String = "SELECT * FROM Details WHERE ItemID = " & contextKey

        Dim da As New SqlDataAdapter(query, constr)
        Dim table As New DataTable()

        da.Fill(table)

        Dim b As New StringBuilder()

        b.Append("<table style='background-color:#f3f3f3; border: #336699 3px solid; ")
        b.Append("width:350px; font-size:10pt; font-family:Verdana;' cellspacing='0' cellpadding='3'>")

        b.Append("<tr><td colspan='3' style='background-color:#336699; color:white;'>")
        b.Append("<b>Budget Item Details</b>")
        b.Append("</td></tr>")
        b.Append("<tr><td style='width:80px;'><b>Detail</b></td>")
        b.Append("<td style='width:80px;'><b>Amount</b></td>")
        b.Append("<td><b>Date</b></td></tr>")

        b.Append("<tr>")
        b.Append("<td>$" & table.Rows(0)("Detail").ToString() & "</td>")
        b.Append("<td>" & table.Rows(0)("Amount").ToString() & "</td>")
        b.Append("<td>" & table.Rows(0)("DetailDate").ToString() & "</td>")
        b.Append("</tr>")

        b.Append("</table>")

        Return b.ToString()
    End Function
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this. You need a `FOR` loop to create rows.

```
Public Shared Function GetDynamicContent(contextKey As String) As String
  Dim constr As String = "Data Source=my data source"
  Dim query As String = "SELECT * FROM Details WHERE ItemID = " & contextKey
  Dim da As New SqlDataAdapter(query, constr)
  Dim table As New DataTable()
  da.Fill(table)
  Dim b As New StringBuilder()
  b.Append("<table style='background-color:#f3f3f3; border: #336699 3px solid; ")
  b.Append("width:350px; font-size:10pt; font-family:Verdana;' cellspacing='0' cellpadding='3'>")
  b.Append("<table style='background-color:#f3f3f3; border: #336699 3px solid; ")
  b.Append("width:350px; font-size:10pt; font-family:Verdana;' cellspacing='0' cellpadding='3'>")
  b.Append("<tr><td colspan='3' style='background-color:#336699; color:white;'>")
  b.Append("<b>Budget Item Details</b>")
  b.Append("</td></tr>")
  b.Append("<tr><td style='width:80px;'><b>Detail</b></td>")
  b.Append("<td style='width:80px;'><b>Amount</b></td>")
  b.Append("<td><b>Date</b></td></tr>")
  For i As Integer = 0 To table.Rows.Count-1
    b.Append("<tr>")
    b.Append("<td>$" & table.Rows(i).Cell("Detail").ToString() & "</td>")
    b.Append("<td>" & table.Rows(i).Cell("Amount").ToString() & "</td>")
    b.Append("<td>" & table.Rows(i).Cell("DetailDate").ToString() & "</td>")
    b.Append("</tr>")
  Next
  b.Append("</table>")
  Return b.ToString()
End Function
```

Comment: Thanks for responding. This loop, for some reason, duplicates the 1st row. If there is 1 row, then it shows it twice. if there are 3 rows, then it shows that same row 4 times.

Comment: Ok, figured out a minor change:

Comment: `code`For i As Integer = 0 To table.Rows.Count - 1
            b.Append("<tr>")
            b.Append("<td>" & table.Rows(i)("Detail").ToString() & "</td>")
            b.Append("<td>$" & table.Rows(i)("Amount").ToString() & "</td>")
            b.Append("<td>" & table.Rows(i)("DetailDate").ToString() & "</td>")
            b.Append("</tr>")
        Next `code`

Comment: mlg74 I am not sure what kind of output you are getting.

Comment: Anyway, this was the answer, the only difference is i added a -1 after rows count